# Ensure ArgoCD running pre-install steps before upgrading

Tags: kubernetes, hook, kubernetes-helm, kong, argocd

When installing Kong with Helm through ArgoCD the installation fails, because ArgoCD can only run `helm upgrade`. So the step initialising the Database is not run, resulting in the pre_migration pod to fail.

The docs statet that i can "Annotate pre-install and post-install with hook-weight: "-1". This will make sure it runs to success before any upgrade hooks." How do i correctly annotate this?

I tried adding:

```
helm.sh/hook = pre-install
helm.sh/hook = weight: -1
```

To the app's configuration using UI in Annotation field. This change is strangely not reflected in manifest.yaml and also not working.

So how do I ensure that ArgoCD runs the pre-install steps of a helm chart beforehand?

Answer (score 1):

This probably works

```
annotations:
  helm.sh/hook: pre-install
  helm.sh/hook-weight: '-1'
```